# Short cut for moving tabs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a shortcut for moving an editor tab to right/left in IntelliJ IDEA like you can do with chrome tabs via `ctrl+shift+[PgUp/PgDown]`?

If not, is there a way to achieve this via macros?

Comment: See also Tab Shifter plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7475-tab-shifter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the TabMover plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10131-tabmover) for this. I have not tried this myself, but by it description it seems that it would work for you.